# Get the values by giving key order as a string path JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way to get the value of

```
{
    "first": "first-string",
    "second-array": [
        {
           "first-Obj": 2
        }
     ]
}
```

is there a way to get or update the values by using a path like string

```
ex: to change the first-obj's value to 1000
    changeTheValueAt('second-array/0/firstObj', 1000)
```

is there any function like above changeTheValueAt or a method.

Comment: You mean update the value on the server? or just locally?

Comment: It's about locally updating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following function for that -

```
function changeTheValueAt(obj, path, value) {
    var parts = path.split("/"),
        final = obj[parts[0]],
        i;

    for (i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < parts.length) {
            final = final[parts[i]];
        }
        else {
            final[parts[i]] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and then call it like this -

```
var ob = {
    "first": "first-string",
    "second-array": [
        {
            "first-Obj": 2
        }
    ]
};

changeTheValueAt(ob, "second-array/0/first-Obj", 1000)

alert(ob["second-array"][0]["first-Obj"]);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xmwtm/2/).

Answer (score -3):

Because second-array is an array, you can't access it by name.  You can access it by index or you can iterate over and find a value and change it when found.

```
var yourObj = {
   "first": "first-string",
   "second-array": [
      {
         "first-Obj": 2
      }
    ]
};

yourObject.second-array[0].first-Obj = 1000;
```

You could do something like:

```
var changeFirstObj = function(node1, node2, new val){
   yourObj[node1].forEach(o, i){
     for(var prop in o){
       if(prop == node2){
          o[node2]=newVal;
        }
   };

   changeFirstObj('second-array', 'first-Obj', 1000);
```

But that's not really very flexible.

Comment: Property names containing `-` are not identifiers, so you can't access them with dot-notation, you have to use brackets. `["first-Obj"]`.